# How to realise while(focused_textarea) with jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm developing a chat website. I have a problem with 'Seen'. Suppose that a message was seen if the user `focusin` on the `<textarea>`. However if a user does not focus off! How can I realise something like this ?

```
while(focused) { 
  // send seen notification 
}
```

Comment: In short - you can't because browser javascript is single threaded and event based. Look at something like jQuery.on ('focus / blur').

Answer (score 0):

You can make a listener to know when a textarea is focused, and when lose focus

```js
$('textarea').on('focus',function(){
    $('.focus').html('true');
});
$('textarea').on('blur',function(){
    $('.blur').html('true');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<textarea></textarea>
<p class="focus">false</p>
<p class="blur">false</p>
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you are better off using something like jQuery and utilizing the .blur() and .focus() method. find the docs for blur() [here](https://api.jquery.com/blur/)